# Autodesk Forge C# - Translate RVT to SVF and display 3D rooms

Tags: c#, space, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I want to display rooms/spaces in the 3d model on forge. I have seen that it is possible : https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-rvt-svf-model-derivative-parameter-generates-additional-content-including-rooms-and-spaces
However i Don't find the relevant code for c# implementation.
Can you help me?

Comment: It is all about Model Derivative API supports one more option generateMasterViews, by which Model Derivative will extract room information. So you could simply add this option when call the endpoint of translation in C#. Maybe your question is about if  NET SDK of Forge has added such option? It looks not yet...I will check with team, while at this moment, you could still post raw HTTP request of translation with the option

Comment: actually, it looks not yet. Thanks, i will try the raw HTTP request and keep you aware

Comment: Hi, just an update: my colleague Kevin has produced a demo code project which implements the logic to translate master view. After translation, you could select which view to display. In Phase view, rooms will be available  https://github.com/kevinvandecar/viewer-walkthrough-online.viewer . In addition, other colleague is working on updating SDK.